# metafor in R - negative coefficent estimates for positive values?

Tags: r, metafor

I'm using the rma.mv function from the metafor package in R for a meta-analysis. My outcome variable is an absolute value, but in exploring the impacts of moderators via meta-regression I'm getting negative estimates for some levels.  A visualization using orchard plots shows the issue:

[image]

I only find this for the one moderator. The model has several random effects, so I'm assuming that's somehow leading to this, but I'm having trouble understanding how this would happen.  Thanks for any  help.

Answer (score 0):

Try regressing onto the logarithm of your output variable, since it's positive and skewed towards 0.  This may help to normalize the model, while simultaneously ensuring that your end-result will be positive.